# AngularJS - Dynamic URL with ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**config.js**

```
angular.module('config', []).constant('ENV',
    {
        name: 'My Angular Project',
        apiEndPoint: 'http://SOMEIP/myServer', //API host,
        adminUrl:'/admin/regionid/site/siteid/admin/regionid', //endpoint
        loginUrl:'/login/regionid/site/siteid/device'

    });
```

**controller.js**

```
this.userLogin = function(username, password) {

var adminServicePath = ENV.apiEndPoint + ENV.adminUrl
//final url = http://SOMEIP/myServer/admin/1/site/1/admin/1

var loginServicePath = ENV.apiEndPoint + ENV.loginUrl
//final url = http://SOMEIP/myServer/login/2/site/2/device


return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: adminServicePath,
            headers: {                       
                "Authorization": "Basic ",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                }
        })

};
```

Here I am appending API with endpoint to form a complete URL. My issue is `regiondid` and `siteid` are dynamic. After user logs in, one REST API request will fetch `siteid` and `regionid` in response.

- How do I dynamically replace `siteid` and `regionid` in URL with ID's
  received in API response? After receiving id's in response, call a function that replaces the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.prototype.replace(substr, newsubstr)`

You can keep `regionID` instead of `?`

```js
var ENV = {
  name: 'My Angular Project',
  apiEndPoint: 'http://SOMEIP/myServer', //API host,
  adminUrl: '/admin/?/site/?/admin/?', //endpoint
  loginUrl: '/login/?/site/?/device'

};


var adminServicePath = ENV.apiEndPoint + ENV.adminUrl.replace("?", 1).replace("?", 1).replace("?", 1);
console.log("Final url admin : " + adminServicePath);

var loginServicePath = ENV.apiEndPoint + ENV.loginUrl.replace("?", 2).replace("?", 2);
console.log("Final url login : " + loginServicePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that the `siteid` and the `regionid` can only be obtained from the response to the login endpoint.

Using a constant might not be the best idea here for obvious reasons (i.e. they're constant, and can't be created at the time you want to create them).

Instead, you could do one of a few things - a simple solution that probably works for a lot of use cases would be to create a login service that wraps your API call and then sets a value either in the service or another service that can be injected into wherever you need it.

It might look like this:

```
angular.module('app')
  .service('loginService', function($http) {
    var siteId,
        regionId;

    function login(username, password) {
      return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '<login endpoint here>',
        headers: {                       
          "Authorization": "Basic ",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
      })
      .then(function(result) {
        siteId = result.siteId;
        regionId = result.regionId;
      });
    }
  );
```

This makes the values available to you any time you need to make an API call after logging in. However, this isn't great since you will need to inject the `loginService` into any controller/service that needs it, and that controller/service might not really care about the login service at all.

An improved approach to this could be to have an API service that performs the http gets/sets/puts/posts/whatever and that is accessed by your data access layer. Inside this service, you can set/get the `siteid` and `regionid`.

It might look like this:

```
angular.module('app')
  .service('api', function($http) {
     var siteId,
         regionId;

     var defaultHeaders = {
       "Authorization": "Basic ",
       "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     };

     function post(url, options) {
       return $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: url,
         headers: options.headers ? options.headers : defaultHeaders
       });
     }

     // Other functions to perform HTTP verbs...
  });

angular.module('app')
  .service('loginService', function(api) {
    function login(username, password) {

      api.post('urlHere', options)
        .then(function(result) {
          api.siteId = result.siteId;
          api.regionId = result.siteId;
        });
    }
  });
```

You can then access the `siteid` and `regionid` where you like.

For example:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('someService', function(api) {
    function doSomethingWithTheApi() {
      var url = 'www.google.com/' + api.siteId + '/' + api.regionId + 'whatever-else';
      return api.post(url, {});
    }
  );
```

Note: the code above isn't complete, but it gives you a very good idea of the approach you could take that is reasonably clean, not too hacky and is easily testable :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: `function post(url, params, options) {
       // Code to make your post here - remember to return a promise.
     }` means API call to fetch siteid and regionid in response ?
What could be params in `api.post('urlHere', params, options)` ? URL will be multiple

Comment: Oh right - I meant that it could be an object that contains the headers for your request (i.e. `headers: { "Authorization": "Basic ", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}`. You can make it as customised as you like :) I'll update the code to show you what I mean.

Comment: As I mentioned, the code I provided you will need to adjust to fit your needs, but it definitely outlines the overall approach to the solution to the problem you are having :)

Comment: I am simply using below code by passing static ID's for now to test. `myApp.service('commonVerbs', function($http) {
    
    var siteId,regionId;

    return function post() {
        siteId = 1;
        regionId = 1;
     }
  });
  
  
//return service;
this.userLogin = function (username, password) {
commonVerbs.post();`
It still says `coomonVerbs.post() is not a function`. Did I miss something ?

Comment: If you look at your code, you'll see that you're doing `return function post()` which isn't correct. It would be easier if you shared your code in a Pastebin paste so I can take a look at it. Also feel free to upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of constant, you can use value.

```
angular.module('config', []).value('ENV',
    {
        name: 'My Angular Project',
        apiEndPoint: '', //API host,
        adminUrl:'', //endpoint
        loginUrl:''

    });
```

Inject ENV and set all values after API call.

```
ENV.name = xyz;
ENV.apiEndPoint = xyz;
ENV.adminUrl = xyz;
ENV.loginUrl = xyz;
```

but the values might get set to default once you refresh the browser.